# Skip list getting lost when either inserting with a new level or adding a new node to lower level

Tags: c, skip-lists

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define Malloc(n, type) (type *)malloc((unsigned)((n) * sizeof(type)))
#define Realloc(ptr, n, type) (type *)realloc(ptr, (n) * sizeof(type))

typedef struct Node
{
    int key;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *down;
} Node;

typedef struct
{
    int level;
    struct Node *header;
} skiplist;

int level()
{
    /*
    This function takes the coin flip and decides the level of the node with each
    level having a probability of 0.25.

    arg: void
    return: a number from the set {1,2,3, 4}
    */
    int level = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        unsigned int coin = (unsigned int)rand();
        coin = coin % 2;
        if (coin)
        {
            level++;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    return level;
}

skiplist skip_list_init();

Node *Traverse_Express(Node *, int);

Node *skip_list_search(skiplist, int);

Node *insert_level(Node *, int, int, int);

void skip_list_insert(skiplist *, int);

void skip_print(skiplist);

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int arr[10000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = (int)rand();
    }
    printf("The array is initialised\n");
    skiplist list;
    list = skip_list_init();
    printf("The Skip list is initialised\n");
    if (list.header == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is null\n");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        skip_list_insert(&list, arr[i]);
        printf("The %d element is initialised with key: %d\n", i, arr[i]);
    }
    printf("The skip list is:\n");
    skip_print(list);
    return 0;
}

void skip_print(skiplist list)
{
    /*
    The function prints the skip list level-wise.

    arg: list
    return: none
    */
    Node *temp = list.header;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = list.level; i > 0; i--)
    {
        printf("The Keys at level %d:\n", i);
        while (NULL != temp->next)
        {
            printf("%d ->", temp->key);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        printf("%d\n", temp->key);
        int dummy = count;
        temp = list.header;
        while (dummy)
        {
            temp = temp->down;
            dummy--;
        }
        count++;
    }
}

skiplist skip_list_init()
{
    /*
    This function creates the first node in the skip list with key value
    to be negative infinity and level of the list =1.

    arg: None
    return: Skiplist initialised with a Node having key as INT_MIN.
    */
    skiplist list;
    Node *head;
    if (NULL == (head = Malloc(1, Node)))
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    list.header = head;
    list.level = 1;
    head->key = INT_MIN;
    head->next = NULL;
    head->down = NULL;
    return list;
}

Node *skip_list_search(skiplist list, int key)
{
    /*
    The function returns a pointer to the either the key itself if present
    or the key immediatedly smaller than the searched key.

    arg:
        list:The skiplist to be searched. Type: skiplist
        key: A key to be searched. Type: int.
    return: Type: Node pointer
        A pointer to the searched key or immediately smaller it.
    */
    if (list.header == NULL)
        exit(1);
    else
        skip_print(list);

    int level = list.level; // Number of levels already present in the list
    Node *curr = list.header;
    printf("Inside Skip search\n");
    printf("The value of level %d\n", level);
    for (; level > 0; level--)
    {
        curr = Traverse_Express(curr, key);
        if ((curr->key == key) && (INT_MIN != curr->key))
        {
            return curr;
        }
        if (NULL != curr->down)
            curr = curr->down;
    }
    printf("The value at current node %d\n", curr->key);
    printf("Leaving Skip_search\n");
    return curr;
}

Node *Traverse_Express(Node *temp, int key)
{
    printf("On the express way\n");
    printf("We are searching the key: %d\n", key);
    while (key > temp->key && NULL != temp->next)
    {
        printf("Loop of expressway\n");
        printf("The current key : %d\n", temp->key);
        if (key >= temp->next->key)
            temp = temp->next;
        else
            break;
    }
    printf("Left the express way\n");
    return temp;
}

Node *insert_level(Node *nod, int key, int lev, int list_lev)
{
    /*
    Inserting the key till the required level

    arg:
        nod: a pointer to the exsiting skip list
        key: key to be inserted
        lev: the level of the key
        list_lev: the number of levels in the given skiplist

    return: A Node pointer to the head of the skiplist with the key 
            inserted to the existing list.
    */
    Node *temp1 = nod, *temp3 = NULL;
    printf("\nStarting of insert at level procedure\n");
    // Procedure to cut-off the extra levels in the list if any
    if (lev < list_lev)
    {
        for (int i = list_lev - lev; i > 0; i--)
        {
            printf("Searching on the level: %d\n", i + lev);
            temp1 = Traverse_Express(temp1, key);
            temp1 = temp1->down;
        }
    }
    printf("The value of first node: %d\n", temp1->key);
    // Procedure to insert from the required level till level 1
    for (int i = 0; i < lev; i++)
    {
        Node *temp2 = Malloc(1, Node);
        temp2->key = key;
        temp2->next = NULL;
        temp2->down = NULL;
        temp1 = Traverse_Express(temp1, key);
        printf("Temp1 current key:%d\n", temp1->key);
        if (NULL == temp1->next)
        {
            temp1->next = temp2;
            printf("Node inserted at level: %d\n", lev - i);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Entered the else procedure\n");
            temp2->next = temp1->next;
            temp1->next = temp2;
            printf("%d\n", temp1->next->key);
        }
        if (i > 0)
        {
            temp3->down = temp2;
        }
        temp1 = temp1->down;
        temp3 = temp2;
        /*
        free(temp2);
        if(temp3==NULL)
        {
            printf("did a fuck up\n");
            exit(1);
        }*/
    }
    skiplist list;
    // list = skip_list_init(list);
    list.header = nod;
    list.level = list_lev;
    printf("Printing skip list from insert level\n");
    skip_print(list);
    printf("End insert level procedure\n\n\n");
    temp1 = temp3 = NULL;
    return nod;
    free(temp1);
    free(temp3);
}

void skip_list_insert(skiplist *list, int key)
{
    /*
    This function finds the key value and if already present, then returns back
    else it inserts the key at its right place.

    arg: a skilplist by reference and a key
    return: None
    */
    printf("Inside skip_list_insert\n");
    Node *req = skip_list_search(*list, key);
    printf("The value returned by skip search %d\n", req->key);
    if (key == req->key)
    {
        printf("Key %d is already present in skip list\n", key);
    }
    Node *temp1 = list->header;
    int list_lev = list->level;
    printf("The list level = %d\n", list_lev);
    int lev = level();
    printf("The prob level %d\n", lev);
    Node *hold_prev = NULL;
    // creating a skip list if level returned is greater than existing one.
    if (lev > list_lev)
    {
        for (int i = lev - list_lev; i > 0; i--)
        {
            skiplist l = skip_list_init();
            Node *inser = Malloc(1, Node);
            printf("The value of i in loop %d\n", i);
            inser->key = key;
            inser->down = NULL;
            inser->next = NULL;
            l.header->next = inser;
            Node *trans = l.header;
            // Zipping the previous levels with new level
            while (NULL != hold_prev)
            {
                trans->down = hold_prev;
                trans = trans->next;
                hold_prev = hold_prev->next;
            }
            hold_prev = l.header;
            l.header = NULL;
            if (hold_prev == NULL)
            {
                printf("Big Mistake");
                exit(1);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("You are doing it correct way\n");
            }
        }
        list->header = hold_prev;
        list->level = lev - list_lev;
        skip_print(*list);
        // Returning a pointer to the zeroth element of last level in this list.
        while (NULL != hold_prev->down)
        {
            hold_prev = hold_prev->down;
        }
    }
    // Inserting the node till the min(list_lev, level())
    if (list_lev > lev)
    {
        temp1 = insert_level(temp1, key, lev, list_lev);
    }
    else
    {
        temp1 = insert_level(temp1, key, list_lev, list_lev);
    }
    skiplist l1 = skip_list_init();
    l1.header = temp1;
    l1.level = list_lev;
    skip_print(l1);

    printf("\n Now the Zipping procedure with level()>list_lev starts\n");
    // Zipping Procedure only if level()>list_lev
    if (lev > list_lev)
    {
        hold_prev->down = temp1;
        skiplist l1 = skip_list_init();
        l1.header = list->header;
        l1.level = lev;
        skip_print(l1);
        printf("the key at the first node:%d\n", temp1->key);
        hold_prev = hold_prev->next;
        while (temp1->key != key)
        {
            temp1 = temp1->next;
            printf("Zipping over keys:\n");
            printf("Current key: %d\n", temp1->key);
        }
        hold_prev->down = temp1;
        list->level = lev;
    }
    if (list_lev > lev)
    {
        list->level = list_lev;
    }
    printf("\n\n\n");
}
```

The above is my implementation. I have tried with all my might to debug the code but I am falling to implement a skip list for past 1 month. I genuinely request with pleading hands  to look into the implementation and please do let me know the fixes, I can do.

It would be a great help. Thank you.

Comment: You must be working from a particular description of how a skip list works. It would help a lot if you included your source.  There are several possible styles of implementation.

Comment: Another suggestion when you run into problems like this is to write a consistency checker.  In this case, you provide the checker with a list of elements that should be found in the list. It traverses the data structure - each of the levels - verifying that everything is as expected. Now do the series of inserts, deletes, and lookups that are demonstrating the error you are seeing, and call the checker after each operation.  This should allow you to get very close to the place where the code is doing something different from what you _think_ it's doing. That's the essence of debugging.

Comment: @Gene [MIT Lecture 12 on skiplists](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-12-skip-lists/)

Comment: @Gene What is ```consistency checker```?

Comment: " In this case, you provide the checker with a list of elements that should be found in the list. It traverses the data structure - each of the levels - verifying that everything is as expected."

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried with all my might to debug the code but I am falling to implement a skip list for past 1 month.

You will have much easier time debugging if you fill the list with some non-random values (you can switch back to random values once the program is working for all hand-coded combinations).

Also fix your comments so they match the code. E.g. here the comments are clearly wrong:

```
skiplist skip_list_init()
{
    /*
    This function creates the first node in the skip list with key value
    to be negative infinity and level of the list =1.

    arg: It takes a list by reference
    return: None
    */
```

There is no `arg` and the return is not None.

You should avoid making a copy of the list when calling `skip_list_search` (pass a *pointer* to the list).

You should avoid this construct:

```
            if (hold_prev == NULL)
            {
                printf("Big Mistake");
                exit(1);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("You are doing it correct way\n");
            }
```

It make your code way too long. Instead, do this:

```
  assert(hold_prev != NULL);
```

Giving your variables meaningful names will also go a long way helping you and others understand the code.

Answer (score 1):

With the value inputs by [Gene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1161878/gene) and [Employed Russian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70483442/11035402), the skip list implementation has a mistake in the function `skip_print` which unfortunately didn't transverse all the levels of the skip-list.
See here:

```
int count=0;
```

and

```
int dummy = count;
temp = list.header;
while (dummy)
{
   temp = temp->down;
   dummy--;
}
count++;
```

When `count=0` implies `dummy=0`. This doesn't let your pointer `temp` transverse to the bottom level till the next iteration when `count=1`. Thus, effectively only transversing and printing till `list.level-1`.

Hence, the implementation doesn't work correctly.

Please incorporate the following code for `skip_print`:

```
void skip_print(skiplist list)
{
    /*
    The function prints the skip list level-wise.

    arg: list
    return: none
    */
    Node *temp = list.header;
    int count = 1;
    while (temp)
    {
        Node *n1 = temp;
        printf("Printing the keys at level: %d\n", count);
        while (NULL != n1->next)
        {
            printf("%d ->", n1->key);
            n1 = n1->next;
        }
        printf("%d\n", n1->key);
        temp = temp->down;
        count++;
    }
}
```

The rest of the code seems to be working fine for me.